# codeigniter 2.02 - passing argument - page not found

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu

i use ubuntu 10.10 and codeigniter 2.0.2
i have successfully installed CI by opening welcome index page
later on i was following tutorial and have added new controller to my project:

```
class Start extends CI_Controller{
    var $base;
    var $css;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->base=$this->config->item('base_url');
        $this->css=$this->config->item('css');
        }


    function hello($name){
        $data['css'] = $this->css;
        $data['base'] = $this->base;
        $data['mytitle'] = 'Welcome to this site';
        $data['mytext'] = "Hello, $name, now we're getting dynamic!";
        $this->load->view('testview', $data);
    }
}
```

as well as view(`testview.php`) and css variable in question. then upon trying to test it by executing `http://localhost/ci/index.php/index/start/hello/fred` i get `404 page not found`.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this class declaration instead

```
class Start extends CI_Controller{
```

and instead of your php4 constructor

use this instead of `Start()`

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->base=$this->config->item('base_url');
    $this->css=$this->config->item('css');
}
```

The actual reason you're getting a 404 is because you're telling it to find a function called `fred`.  The url you're probably meaning to hit is this...

```
http://localhost/ci/index.php/start/hello/fred
```

Since 2.0.x , Codeigniter has changed their base controller class names and moved everything to php5 style constructors, among other things.

You are probably following a older tutorial.

Comment: yep didn't look to closely at the base of the url, just noticed he wasn't calling the `hello` function.

Comment: i have done as you told but still same problem. is it some apache configuration thing?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have used an old tutorial.  In CodeIgniter 2, some things are different.

1. `extend CI_Controller` instead of `extend Controller`
2. Use `__construct` for constructors instead of the class name.

   ```
   function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       // More stuff
   }
   ```
3. The url should be `http://localhost/ci/index.php/start/hello/fred`.  CodeIgniter's URLs are used like so:

   ```
   http://localhost/ci/index.php/<controller>/<method>/<params>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this answer as i got the idea of it's url working. :)